# Is it possible to pin a windows to the desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, desktop-customization

I am looking at pinning the window from an application to the desktop in Windows 7. 
I do not want this window to be on top of the others, just "glued" to the desktop.

It could look like what used to be the dynamic desktop in XP (I do not remember the exact name, it was basically the ability to display a web page on the desktop)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The dynamic desktop was removed from Windows.  There might be a third-party application that duplicates that functionality but the feature built-into Windows was removed because of security concerns.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes I know - I gave the dynamic desktop analogy just for the look-and-feel of what I am looking for.

Comment: It was Active Desktop. BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible if the docking isn't programmed in the spesific sofwtare itself (for example, Microsoft's OneNote **does** have the ability to be docked to desktop). 
The most close option is aero snap - choose a window and click Windows Key + Left / Right.

Comment: The problem with Aero Snap is that the windows remains a window, just resized: pressing WinKey-M minimizes it, etc.

Comment: I know, that why I said "the most close option". However, I will do some further research about this - it's possible that there is a 3rd party software to enable this. If I'll find one, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well, the only thing I could fing about docking to the side of the desktop in Win7 is [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/848edecd-184e-4c59-acfd-2f917d8a1de8/how-do-you-dock-folders-to-the-side-of-the-desktop-like-in-windows-2k-xp-and-vista), ad there is no actual answer there, every answer is refering to programs like [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/), which are not relevant.

Comment: OK, I was able to find [this list of software](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-window-manager-resizer-arranger.htm). It's not *docking*, but the programs there have the ability to snap windows **and** make the on top, so that combination should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tool (not free) that allows you to keep a particular window always open on the desktop, preventing minimizing the window. The window is on (in?) the desktop very much like "active desktop" of old so other windows can cover it. (the window will also ignore start+D and Alt+Tab)

http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/help/features/pintodesktop.php